# Meteor don't close Mongo connections?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using Meteor JS in production and it first looked like we suffered from a memory leak in our application, but now it seems like MongoDB is the culprit or perhaps Meteor?

We're heavy users of Meteor methods and don't manage connection to Mongo ourselves, since Meteor does that for us. However, in production it seems like mongo processes just hangs around forever and consumes more and more memory until the application becomes unresponsive.

[image: MongoDB processes in prod]

As you clearly can see, there are a lot of mongo processes here, some that has been living for hours. Yesterday, after a reboot of the server the memory consumption was about 900MB, now it's closing onto 4GB.

Since rebooting every once in a while in unacceptable, what can we do to fix this? I don't really know where to start since Meteor manages connections to Mongo and I am a bit uncertain what's causing this issue.

Any tips or direction is helpful, even if it's just a tip on how to debug our application.

**MeteorJS version**: 1.10

**Mongo version**: 4.2.1

Comment: There are similar topics in the forums [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/memory-utilization-is-running-high/51371/4) and [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/cpu-spikes-after-upgrade-meteor-to-1-10-2/53200) but our apps for example never have these issues. How do you deploy? Can you add your anonymized deployment config here?

Comment: Use currentOp etc. to figure out what your actual connection situation is.

Comment: Have you used publish subscribe?? If yes try to stop subscriptions after getting data.